# How can I open an external program in JavaFrame Window?

Tags: java

How can I open an external program like Word or Notepad in a `JavaFrame` Window, and not in an external window?

Comment: Opening an external program inside your window? pretty paradoxical and meaningless.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to achieve?  e.g. open word documents, edit plain text files

Comment: ok I will explain to you what I want to do .I have a task ( part of project ) to provide virtual keyboard in java and use it write text in word or notepad ,etc. My virtual keyboard is done and I test it for writing text in text filed. now I want to use this keyboard to other application

Answer (score -1):

If you want a rich text editor inside your Java program, just use something like JTextPane.

Comment: no, i want to run any app i.e. Microsoft PowerPoint inside the JavaFrame !

Comment: Why don't you want to run it in it's own Frame? You can have a button in your frame that executes it.

Comment: Yeah I guess I just have absolutely no idea why you would want or need to to this..

Comment: @JavaX "i want to run any app .. inside the JavaFrame !"  I want a pony, doesn't mean I'm going to get one.  And as an aside, why would the end user want a (mostly useless) Java frame wrapped around their other software?

Comment: In addition, I would think this would not only be unnecessary, but would also make the program platform dependent. If you're trying to get Office to run on whatever platform you run Java on, this is not the way to go.

Comment: ok I will explain to you what I want to do. I have a task ( part of project ) to provide virtual keyboard in java and use it write text in word or notepad ,etc. My virtual keyboard is done and I test it for writing text in text filed. now I want to use this keyboard to other application

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question. I think it's a poor question, but, this still doesn't answer it...